# Parameters of 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' has different optionality than expected by protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager, optional-parameters

I have implemented *CLLocationManagerDelegate* in my viewcontroller and I am getting the following warnings

> Parameters of 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' have different
>   optionality than expected by protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'
>
> Parameters of 'locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)' have different
>   optionality than expected by protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'
>
> Parameter of 'locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:)' has
>   different optionality than expected by protocol
>   'CLLocationManagerDelegate'

From this what I understood
"
***Optionality of parameters(whether the variable is optional or not) is different from what is there in original protocol method definition***
"

But I couldn't find any difference between the original and what I have with me.

*Here it is*

**In Protocol definition**

```
optional public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

optional public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)

optional public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```

**In my implementation of the protocol**

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
        didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
        didFailWithError error: NSError)

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
        didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```

My xcode version is 7.1.1

So can anybody explain me why the warnings are popping up ?

Comment: Try to re-implement the functions by typing `loc` and using code completion

Comment: Its not coming up in code completion

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the protocol implementation. Did you `import CoreLocation` ?

Comment: Yes I imported it and the method is available at `CLLocationManagerDelegate` as well

Comment: Here is the snapshot of implementation http://postimg.org/image/51de7d69d/

Comment: That looks normal. Did you also add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in the `class`  line of the view controller?

Comment: Yeah buddy,it's already added over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the xcode solved the problem...sometimes things are strange